# what is the difference between != and !== in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Are `!=` and `!==` are respectively the same as `==` and `===`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`!==` and `===` are strict comparison, and `==` / `!=` are loose comparison. It's best to use strict comparison.

Comment: Well, i think loose comparisons are useful.

Comment: I didn't say they weren't, but if you're used to using strict comparison and only use loose when it's useful to, you're going to run into a lot less bugs (generally.)

Comment: That's not a sufficient answer. Iit is better, because ... ? You are running into a lot less bugs, because ...?

Answer (score 6):

`true == 1` gives you true

`true === 1` gives you false

Reason is that == compares only the value (so that 1, '1' is considered as true)

=== compares the value and the type.

Same thing in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

== compares the value of object while === compares the object value and type.

Comment: That would mean `[1] == [1]` and that you cannot do `1 === 1` as numbers have no reference.

Comment: by reference, i meant value & type. See edit

Answer (score 2):

yes it is.

```
<script>   

    var str = '1234';
    var int = parseInt('1234');

    if (int !== str)
    {
       alert('returns true and alerts');
    }

    if (int === str)
    {
       alert('returns false');
    }
</script>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/c801e.php